# Flutter: a customized widget that acts as a FAB, Inkwell does not respect the circular shape and ripples are rectangular

Tags: flutter

For adding a glow effect on a button I have "Frankenstein-ed" this code:

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          blurRadius: 50.0,
        ),
      ]),
      child: Material(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){print('tap');},
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), child: Icon(Icons.add)),
        ),
      ), //Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
```

the shape in `Material` is circular, but the ripple effect that are handled by Inkwell goes outside the circle shape.

I have tried wrapping `Inkwell` by a `Container`:

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){print('tap');},
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), child: Icon(Icons.add)),
          ),
        ),
```

and wrapping `Padding` by a `Container`:

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          blurRadius: 50.0,
        ),
      ]),
      child: Material(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){print('tap');},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), child: Icon(Icons.add)),
          ),
        ),
      ), //Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
```

but no luck.

Edit after Gaspard Merten's answer:

trying this code does not change the ripple effect's behavior:

```
Material(
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  color: Colors.pink,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
      new BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        blurRadius: 50.0,
      ),
    ]),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onClick();
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), child: Icon(icon)),
      ),
    ), //Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ClipRRect and clip the material widget instead of the container:

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),
  child: YourMaterialButton
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the material widget is the direct ancestor of the inkwell. Try to put the Material widget before the container and specify de coloris and the border radius of the material and remove the color argument from the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'customBorder' property to make ripple shape circular irrespective of container shape !

```
InkWell(
    customBorder: CircleBorder(),
    onTap: () {}
    child: ...
)
```